# Separating caption of first figure from top of second figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

I am setting two TikZ subfigures on top of each other by setting `1\textwidth` for both subfigures.

Now, the caption of the first figure is really close to the top of the second figure. Is there any way to put in some space between them?

```
\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{...} 
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{...} 
\end{subfigure}

\caption{...}        
\label{...}

\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\vspace{...}` like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{...}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{2ex}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{...}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{...}
\label{...}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to set the `\belowcaptionskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{2ex}      %%%<-- put here to make it local
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{...}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{...}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{...}
\label{...}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```